# React onmouseleave isn't leaving the target element properly

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple list of rows which have `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` event listeners which simply add/remove a class to the target element. The problem is that when your cursor leaves the element, the class isn't immediately removed which results in multiple rows sometimes having the hovered class simultaneously.

Does anyone know why this happens and what the best fix is?

Thanks for any help here. Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7knhjp?file=src%2Fcomponents%2Fshow-subs.js) demo, or the relevant code for `show-subs.js` is below:

```
import React from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

export default class ShowSubs extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            subs: null,
            subCount: null
        };
        
        // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
        this.onMouseEnterHandler = this.onMouseEnterHandler.bind(this);
        this.onMouseLeaveHandler = this.onMouseLeaveHandler.bind(this);
      }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = 'https://em-app-basic.herokuapp.com/emails-api';
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({
            subs: data.subs,
            loading: false,
            subCount: data.subs.length,
            hover: false
        })
    }

    onMouseEnterHandler(e) {
        this.setState({
            hover: true
        });
        console.log('enter');
        e.target.classList.add('hovered');
    }
    
    onMouseLeaveHandler(e) {
        this.setState({
            hover: false
        });
        console.log('leave');
        e.target.classList.remove('hovered');
    }

    clickTest() {
        console.log('click');
    }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
        return <div>loading...</div>
    }

    if (!this.state.subs) {
        return <div>no data to load.</div>
    }

    return (
    <div>
        {this.state.subCount ? 
        <div class="inner-details">
            <div class="recent-details">
                Total Subs: <span class="sub-count">{this.state.subCount}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        : null}
        <div id="users-grid-container">
            <h1 id="users-intro">Viewing Some Subscribers</h1>
            {<div id="users-grid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="user-col">Name</div>
                    <div class="user-col">Email</div>
                    <div class="user-col">Tag</div>
                    <div class="user-col">Subscription Date</div>
                    <div class="user-col view"></div>
                </div>
                {this.state.subs.map((sub, i) => 
                    <div className="row" key={i}
                    onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnterHandler}
                    onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeaveHandler}
                    onClick={this.clickTest}>
                        <div className="user-col name">{sub.name}</div>
                        <div className="user-col email">{sub.email}</div>
                        <div className="user-col tag">{sub.tag}</div>
                        <div className="user-col date">{sub.subDate}</div>
                        <div className="user-col view">
                            <Link to={`/sub/${sub._id}`} className="view-sub">View</Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>}
        </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: i am not seeing the issue it works fine, the class `hovered` does not get assigned to more than one item

Comment: that's strange because I can see the hovered class assigned to multiple nodes simultaneously. Does this happen to anyone else?

Comment: https://ibb.co/25QSQ0f here it is on my screen